How do I open a file in the Ubuntu system folder?
I'm trying to get the information from the loadavg file in the Ubuntu folder but even with the absolute path it still doesn't work.
Here's my current code.It always return the error case.
int main(char const *filepath)
{
    char buffer[1000];
    int fd = open("/proc/loadavg", O_RDWR);
    ssize_t read_fd;

    if (fd != -1) {
        read_fd = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
        while (read_fd > 0){
            buffer[read_fd] = '\0';
            my_putstr(buffer);
            read_fd = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
        }
    } else {
        my_putstr("An error happenned when opening the file\n");
        exit(84);
    }
}


If you only want to read from the file, why are you opening it in read and write mode? Also, if you have an error, use e.g. perror to print the error message. Or use strerror to get a pointer to a string explaining the error.

On my system /proc/loadavg is read only. I'd be curious what you get from the strerror message.

Print the error. See errno and strerror and perror.

Thanks i had just figured it out but you are right the problem was my RDWR flag as the proc files are in read-only mode.The correct flag was RDONLY.
